# Mapeamento de rota não funciona no ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Sempre utilizei ASP.NET MVC 4 e agora estou aprendendo ASP.NET Core na versão 2.2, estou fazendo alguns testes e notei que o roteamento não está funcionando.

Estou utilizando o projeto padrão que já vem configurado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro de `Startup.cs` configuro a rota da seguinte maneira:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
 }
```

Então insiro o seguinte na página `index.cshtml`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link para a Action About no mesmo controlador", "About")
```

Porém quando vou ver o resultado na View `Index.cshml` me é retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: Você tá usando ASP.NET "normal" com .NET Core? O.o

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: No asp.net core tens uma forma mais "limpa" de criar links
    <a asp-action="About">Link para a Action About no mesmo controlador</a>
Além do action podes especificar a Area e o Controller.

Comment: Outra coisa importante no .net core (que já era no MVC 4) é respeitar as convenções (regras de código), o compilador/interpretador respeita essas regras na hora de interpretar o teu código, refiro isto porque na estrutura do teu projeto faltam algumas das pastas da convenção MVC... para o ActionLink o controller e o action tem que existir e respeitar a convenção para serem reconhecidos como tal. Só assim na hora de gerar o link o .net core saberá qual a route correta para gerar o <a href=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O projeto que você está trabalhando não é do template do **MVC**, a rota que você diz que não funciona porque não existem controllers ou views nessa estrutura. Você iniciou seu projeto escolhendo a opção de Web Application, também conhecido como **Razor Pages** que tem por padrão de rota inicial a **página** index.

[image: Adicionando novo projeto]

[image: Estrutura RazorPages]

Pegando como exemplo a página About, para onde você queria criar o `ActionLink`, perceba que ela é composta por um template Razor (.cshmtl) com o bind à uma classe de `PageModel` (cshtml.cs), que vai controlar as suas ações em forma de eventos... como se fossem as actions de uma controller.

**About.cshml**

```
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

**About.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication.Razor.Pages
{
    public class AboutModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Your application description page.";
        }
    }
}
```

E nessa estrutura, para você adicionar um link na Index para a about, basta você adicionar na Index.cshml a seguinte marcação:

```
<a asp-page="/About">About</a>
```

Contudo, se você deseja continuar trabalhando com o MVC no asp.net core, basta você criar o seu projeto utilizando o templante "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)".

[image: Criando projeto MVC]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A estrutura é quase a mesma da que você está acostumado no **MVC4**, porém implementação os recursos disponíveis são um tanto diferente. E segue abaixo forma recomendada de criar o seu `ActionLink` nessa versão.

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta faltando O Controller e as Views, sugiro que crie outro projeto. E apos isso você configura o controller pra renderizar as paginas que vocÊ quer